# Excel Addin -> Custom Pane -> Not clickable while cell editing

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, excel-addins, webview2

I've created a custom pane in my Excel Addin using winforms control with WebView2 to host an html page.

I've noticed that when user is editing a cell, the html page within the form is not responding.

I have a function from a script inside the html which calls back to the form on events.

```
function toWindows(msg) {
    window.chrome.webview.postMessage(msg);
}
```

On the WebView2 side, however, I do not get any event on the CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived callback.
I've noticed pane is not responsive also with a basic form.
I would like to receive callbacks to WebView2 on html clicks however, since Ribbon buttons are responsive on cell editing, and I would like to have the same behavior.

Any ideas?

Comment: WebView2 runs entirely on the UI thread on which it is created https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/threading-model. I'm not familiar with Excel Addin threading model. While editing a cell and such, is Excel blocking the UI thread and so WebView2 isn't receiving messages?

Comment: Ribbon buttons are still active and clickable while editing a cell . The click callbacks I get come from UI thread, so I don't think UI thread is blocked at that time, unless I am missing something here.